# Preposition Bis in accusative case

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case, accusative

> Bis zu ihrem Abschluss in Psychologie möchte Andrea nicht umziehen.

Why **ihrem** after akkusative bis?

Comment: In what way do you consider *bis* an accusative preposition? It's not, it  takes complements either without overt case markers ("bis bald") or governed by a construction other than the "bis" ("bis nächsten Montag" - temporal accusative; "bis zum Wahnsinn" - dative governed by "zu").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Bis* is always an accusative preposition. Here the preposition that governs the case is *zu* (an always-dative preposition), that is why you have *ihrem* instead of *ihren*.

Comment: Good explanation, that was the piece I'm missing.

Comment: Thanks for filling the gap c.p.

Answer (score 2):

The preposition "bis" can be used with the german Akkusativ and Dativ as well.
Usually "bis" with Akkusativ but if you use "bis zu" then the Dativ may follow (Temporal preposition).

Usually one can omit the "zu" when using "bis zu" and it seems "bis" would required always Dativ which is not true. You can find and construct a variety of sentences using either of the casi.

Best wishes,
SG

Comment: Thanks. Strange that this sentence used as an example of the accusative case here:https://www.deutsch-als-fremdsprache-lernen.de/deutsche-substantive-praepositionen-mit-akkusativ/

Comment: Well, I don't know about this website or can give you a more rigorous grammatical explanation, however what I stated is usually true. Maybe somebody else can chime in?

Comment: I just wonder why they used this sentence (which is akkusative + dative) in the plain accusative example...thanks.

Comment: Bis cannot be used with dative, so the first sentence is missleading.

Comment: Well this is true, you will have to add zu/zum in addition which makes the "compound" preposition Dative?

Comment: @stephanmg Indeed